# GOOGLE sheet ImportHTML for calculating Dividend History

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import Dividend data of a stock into a google sheet but I am getting error stating that could not fetch URL but if I tried to connect to the NASDAQ website manually then its working perfectly. I am not sure what's causing this issue.
Your help is highly appreciated.

**Query Used**

=QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl/dividend-history", "table", 3), "select Col3")

**Error**

```
Could not fetch url: https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl/dividend-history
```

Answer (score 0):

#### This may be a bug

This looks like it may be a issue on Google's side:

> https://issuetracker.google.com/175144626

There has not been any resolution, but go and star that issue if it affects you or you want updates.

Answer (score 0):

I found that string but it doesn't work either:

=QUERY(IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/"&A2&"/dividend-history");"//tbody//tr[1]"); "select Col1, Col3 LIMIT 1")

It should return the Ex-Div Date and the next quarterly Dividend amount.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer or a request for clarification? In the first case, please read [answer] and then edit this to clarify. In the latter case, please refrain from posting answers that are not answers. You can earn reputation by asking and answering questions that don't require clarification. Once you earn [50 reputation points you will be able to comment on other users' posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).